# ordered change of a string (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create some kind of game, where user must to guess a word, tapping right symbol on alphabet. When the user's guess is correct, code must replace all the "_ " to a correct character. My code replaces a line of "_ " with a correct characters, but in wrong order.

```
var secretW = document.getElementById('secretWord'); //id of div elem
var guessWord = "someword"; // the word to guess
for (var x = 0; x < guessWord.length; x++) {
    secretW.innerHTML += '<span class="lineStyle">_ </span>';
} // creates a pattern, so user knows how many symbols to guess
```

This code checks clicked character of it's match:

```
for (var i = 0; i < on.length; i++){
    on[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var whatLetter = this.innerHTML;
        var num = 0;
        var trueCount = 0;
        for (num = 0; num < guessWord.length; num++) {
            if (whatLetter == guessWord.charAt(num)) {
                secretW.innerHTML = secretW.innerHTML.replace('_ ', whatLetter);
                trueCount++;
            } else if (whatLetter != guessWord.charAt(num)) {
                secretW.innerHTML = secretW.innerHTML.replace('_ ', '_ ');
            } 
        }
        if (trueCount == 0) {
            mistake();
        }
    });
}
```

It's purpose is if the user clicks "s" show every "s" of the word in right order 
for example: 
1) word is "someword" 
2) div shows: `_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _`
3) user clicks "o" button
4) div shows: "`_ o _ _ _ o _ _`"
in my code it does:
"`o o _ _ _ _ _ _` "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with `innerHTML.replace` you can't select a specific occurrence of the `_` you want to replace (it replaces the first one it finds).

Instead you can select n-th `.lineStyle` element inside the `#secretWord` and change its conents.

```
if (whatLetter == guessWord.charAt(num)) {
  secretW.getElementsByClassName("lineStyle")[num].innerHTML=whatLetter;
  trueCount++;
}
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8zbzxrp/1/) for demo (try clicking the `o`)